# Test if Clojure Om Next component satisfies? a protocol

Tags: clojure, om

In Clojure (not ClojureScript), how can I check that a given component implements a protocol?

```
(defui MyComp
  static my-protocol
  (aaa [this] []))

(satisfies? my-protocol MyComp) ;; false
(satisfies? om.next.protocols/IReactChildren MyComp) ;; false
;; but
(.aaa ( MyComp nil nil nil nil)) ;; []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand now, this is not supported directly by om.next, since `defui` does not behave exactly like `defrecord`.

One way (used by untangled) is to put the implementation of the protocol in the `meta`data. Conversation with tony kay:

> tony.kay [6:02 PM] So defui in clj land adds the "protocol" things to
>   metadata just a sec...
>   https://github.com/untangled-web/untangled-client/blob/0b2fdfec1f0dde2d1d95b5a4d092131ca6fdc8f4/src/untangled/client/core.cljc#L90-L96
>   this is why we need functions like `get-initial-state`. We can call
>   the protocol ones in cljs, but not in clj because js allows his macro
>   to hack them into place Om components have to be stock React
>   components for interop, so we don't actually use protocols per-se,
>   just emulate the syntax this is part of the cleanup work that we need
>   to comb over in a lot of our docs/guide for sever-side rendering. You
>   cannot, for example, call `initial-state` in your UI and expect
>   clj-land to like it but many of our examples were written before it
>   existed, and are now technically wrong if you want to do ss rendering

This is also how it is done inside om.next for server-side rendering.

It can also be seen in om-css https://github.com/ladderlife/om-css/blob/dd19235dabca74db1669504fff941ff97abddcc4/src/main/om_css/core.cljc#L240-L242

Unfortunately since these approach require overwriting `defui` they do not compose together very well.

Comment: Om Next does the metadata thing for the "static" protocols. So, if you follow the model of `get-initial-state` it will work. The JVM doesn't support the idea of implementing an interface on the instance of the Class that represents your new class (which is what the `static` thing is emulating in js).